# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219 in laravel API's

Tags: php, laravel-5

routes.php

I want to use in API's and I don't have forms to declare the method.

```
Route::post('update/{id}','MovieController@updateRecord');
Route::delete('delete/{id}','MovieController@deleteRecord');
```

Comment: You can use postman in chrome web store.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) from google web store it's a great tool to test your API's

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file app\Http\Kernel.php

And comments the following middlewareGroups

```
  \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        //\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        //\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        //\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];
```